# How does Ubuntu Cloud Guest and Amazon web services work?

Tags: server, cloud, amazon-ec2

Could you explain me what I can do with ubuntu cloud and amazon cloud (Amazon EC2). How are they usefull.

Can I use it like a real PC or it is only like a simple cloud wich can I put some files or maybe a site?
I'm confused about their use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine that you need to set up a server to work as a Web Site hosting server, or email server, or some specific server, for example, you have a service like Dropbox(I mean you are the guy that owns Dropbox for example) and you want to set the server for it. In case that there are a lot of users you need to get a high speed internet to it, than take care of hardware not to fail so you don't have downtimes, hard disk space, software updates, all the technical stuff you need to do in order to keep a server...

So what Amazon EC2, Windows Azure... do: they take care of all that, you don't even know what happens behind there or you don't even know what hardware or software is sitting there, you never get to touch the server, you just put your servers and applications on it and they take care of the hardware, bandwidth... They set up the servers for you and take care of it(backups, additional hardware in case that something fails...)

Here is a link from Microsoft site where they explain uses cases: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/saas/

I do want to point out that almost no serious site is using Windows Azure :)
The only more serious site that is using it is a Government site in one country...

Edit: P.S just a few days ago (29 February to 1 March) all Windows Azure servers failed and had a 9-12+ hour downtime because of a Microsoft miscalculation in the leap year...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Moraru said, you can try the Amazon ECS Cloud services yourself.

You do need to sign up for an account however Amazon offers a free monthly tier for 1 year

**Free Tier**

**As part of AWS’s Free Usage Tier, new AWS customers can get started with Amazon EC2 for free. Upon sign-up, new AWS customers receive the following EC2 services each month for one year:**

```
750 hours of EC2 running Linux/Unix Micro instance usage
750 hours of EC2 running Microsoft Windows Server Micro instance usage
750 hours of Elastic Load Balancing plus 15 GB data processing
30 GB of Amazon Elastic Block Storage (EBS) plus 2 million IOs and 1 GB snapshot storage
15 GB of bandwidth out aggregated across all AWS services
1 GB of Regional Data Transfer
```

Head over to http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/ for more information

Comment: He asked about Amazon EC2 so I thought he knows about Amazon EC2 :)

Comment: You gave a great answer, all I could do was link the Amazon site :)